# calculation with select option value using javascript

Tags: select, jquery-calculation

I have query related to javascript that we call a function where is id in select option tag. So can we use this id for calculation in other function? how to get this id? If yes then how? If no then please give me some other idea..

How to read this id?

Give me result soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.val()`, see [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fleuv/pquo2g8k). Here i'm using `.change()` you probably want to use `.submit` for this.

Comment: It is working nice! here only one dropdowb select box when i working with more then one it is not working correctly.How can i do it?